# Type of input C#

Tags: c#

Actually I'm trying to write small program that read input from user to decide whether is it `integer` or not.

```
object x=Console.ReadLine();
check(x);

static void  check(object x)
{   
     if (x.GetType() == typeof(int))
      Console.WriteLine("int");
     else
      Console.WriteLine("not int");   

}
```

Comment: Int.TryParse it the way to go

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` always returns a string. A string can _contain_ numbers.

Comment: so what is the question?

Answer (score 12):

You can use this:

```
string x = Console.ReadLine();

int i;

if(int.TryParse(x, out i))
     Console.WriteLine("int");
 else
     Console.WriteLine("not int");
```

If the `TryParse()` returns `true`, the parsed value is stored in `i`

Answer (score 6):

Just use [Int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) as in this example

```
int result;
string x = Console.ReadLine();
if(int.TryParse(x, out result))
  Console.WriteLine("int");
else
  Console.WriteLine("not int");
```

The method accepts the input string and an integer variable. If the string can be converted to an integer number, then the integer variable is initialized with the converted string and the method returns true. Otherwise the method returns false and the integer variable passed will be set to zero.

As a side note. [Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) returns a string

Answer (score 4):

try

```
static void  check()
{   int result
    string x = Console.ReadLine();
    if(int.TryParse(x, out result)
      Console.WriteLine("int");
    else
      Console.WriteLine("not int");   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int isInteger;
Console.WriteLine("Input Characters: ");
string x = Console.ReadLine();
if(int.TryParse(x, out isInteger)
  Console.WriteLine("int");
else
  Console.WriteLine("not int");
```

Comment: Sorry I was typing when I did this maybe we have the same idea but we all know that the question is easy so there will be circumstances that the answer will be the same to others.

Comment: Yeah I know, just saying. Maybe add a link, some more details or something extra.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ReadLine()` Will Always Return String . So you can Try `Int.TryParse()` To Check the type. Check the bellow Example

```
   int output;
   string x = Console.ReadLine();
   if(int.TryParse(x, out output)
       Console.WriteLine("int");
   else
      Console.WriteLine("not int");
```

hope This may helpful for you.